# How to overflow image inside Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an oversized image to fix inside a bootstrap row with the size col of 12. But whenever I do this, the image makes the row stretch all the way across and outside of the screen. I want keep the row width the same, but have it overflow with a scroll if the image gets too big inside the div. How should I do this? Below is the code that I've got.

**HTML**

```
<div id="imageRow" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id='imgContainer' runat="server" class='imgContainer' visible="false">
                <asp:Image runat='server' ID='imgDocument' Visible="false" CssClass='imgDocument clear'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

P.S. I tried using Max-width, but it doesn't work as this will just simply limits the width of my image to fix inside the div without a scrollbar for it. I.e. it won't allow it to go oversize

Comment: add `image-responsive` class to the image

Comment: @Vishnu Thanks for the info. It kind of works, but it limits the width of the image to fix into it? I don't want to limit the size of the image, I want to make it so that you can scroll across the image inside the row div

Comment: I think. example code pen link have solution.
https://codepen.io/greatzspido/pen/jGKwNw
and If <img> tag have max-width:100% in your code so do reset.

Comment: @himanshugupta Thanks. By looking at your example, I found out I've missed out the `container` class that needs wrapping around :)

Comment: Thanks and now I can post my comment as an answer :). please make thumb up to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this example CodePen link has a solution: https://codepen.io/greatzspido/pen/jGKwNw

Do some checks also in your code:

1. If `img` tags have `max-width:100%` do a reset.
2. Add an element with the `container` class to wrap your content.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS code as below.

```
.imgContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. The problem is the max-width - it limits the size of the image which doesn't even show the scrollbar because it won't even go over the max-width of 100% in this example.

Comment: Please can you provide a working fiddle? Then I'll help you to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a newer solution. Add this to the image:

`.image {
  object-fit: fill;
}`